# Insertion of multiple data

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How to insert multiple values into a Sharepoint List Column. I have one sharepoint listcolumn named Technology of type Choices. When i hitted Save button after the selection of mutiple checkboxes, it will stored to that of particular column seperated by a semi column. Help me with a example..
[alt text http://img145.imageshack.us/i/storing.jpg/](http://img145.imageshack.us/i/storing.jpg/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom workflow for that, using the Sharepoint Designer. Associate the work flow with it, and after its save, you can create custom steps to save data in multiple sources.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101005911033.aspx